# make pointer disappear in full screen jwplayer 6

Tags: javascript, flash, jwplayer

is there some code I can add to setup which will achieve this or is it a case of configuring files or making a new skin.

```
<head>
  <script src="/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>

      <div id='my-video'></div>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
      wplayer('my-video').setup

        ({
             file: 'clash.mp4',
             width: '480',
             height: '270',
        });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that we are going to fix.